# Balancing with MX records - How does this work?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, email-server, internal-dns, dns-hosting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Wk0.png)please can you help me with this, I have this scenario to balance email traffic, currently, most of the emails are going towards imail2.test.com.pe and imail.test.com.pe and some fewer towards imaill3.test.com.pe and imail1.test.com.pe, the first thing I would like to know is why, honestly Ive not had this case before and I dont know why I have 4 MX records.

MX records for test.com.pe:

test.com.pe  MX preference = 20, mail exchanger =mail2.test.com.pe

test.com.pe  MX preference = 50, mail exchanger =imaill3.test.com.pe

test.com.pe  MX preference = 10, mail exchanger =imail.test.com.pe

test.com.pe  MX preference = 30, mail exchanger =imail1.test.com.pe

A records:

imail2.test.com.pe      internet address = 84.5.6.9

imaill3.test.com.pe     internet address = 100.25.65.8

imail.test.com.pe       internet address = 84.5.6.9

imail1.test.com.pe      internet address = 100.25.65.8

My second question is, how can I switch all the emails towards the IP 84.5.6.9( imail2.test.com.pe and imail.test.com.pe)?, should I set 0 as the preference for imail2.test.com.pe and imail.test.com.pe?

Answer (score 4):

The MX record preference is used when more than one MX record is entered for any single domain name that is using more than one mail server. In this case the preference number indicates the order in which the mail servers should be used. This enables the use of primary and backup mail servers.

So if you want to load balance you should give the records equal priority.

You can find more information [here](https://support.mailessentials.gfi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015115760-How-to-Load-Balance-Incoming-Email-Using-DNS-MX-Records) about load balancing emails.